# Convert form request data to xml in cakephp

Tags: php, html, forms, cakephp, request

I'm trying to convert all the form data in a cakephp request object to xml and then convert that to a string so that I can place it in a (blob) column in a mysql table.

I'm trying to do this current using the buildin xml builders in CakePHP 2.x.x as shown below but am getting an error.

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Survey->create();                 
                        $xml = Xml::build($this->request->data);

}
```

The form is shown below

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Survey'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add Survey'); ?></legend>
    <?php

                echo $this->Form->input('Question 1');
                echo $this->Form->input('Question 2');
                echo $this->Form->input('Question 3');

    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

The error I'm getting seems to be due to the DOCDocument->createElement(string,string) in the stacktrace. I've also used other methods including building it manually like so:

```
                $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
                $doc->formatOutput = true;
                $doc->loadHTML($this->request->data); 

                $data = $this->request->input('Xml::build',
                        array('return' => 'domdocument'));

                while(list($key,$value) = each($this->request->data)){
                    $data = $data . $key . $value;
                }

                if(isset($this->request->data)){
                    $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
                    $doc->formatOutput = true;
                    $root = $doc->appendChild($doc->createElement('survey'));


                    $post = $this->request->data['Survey'];
                    unset($post['submit']);

                    foreach($post as $key => $value){
                        $node = $doc->createElement($key,$value);
                        $root->appendChild($node);
                    }

                    $test1 = $doc->saveXML();
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/xml.html#transforming-an-array-into-a-string-of-xml) the transforming an array into a string of XML section.

Comment: I'm getting an error. It says an Internal error has occurred when i do $xml = Xml::build($this->request->data, array('return' => 'simplexml'));

Comment: never mind, I read the document more carefully and realized I was sending an invalid xml. Thanks you for response.